# How to mount manually created non-expiring service account token into the pod

Tags: kubernetes, token, service-accounts

Let's say that the token for the service accout is manually created using

```
kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: build-robot-secret
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/service-account.name: build-robot
type: kubernetes.io/service-account-token
EOF
```

How do I mount the service account token thus created into the pod? I was under the assumption that the pod created should have this service account token mounted into /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount when serviceAccountName: build-robot is part of the manifests and shouldn't have an expiry but then when the token is inspected, there is an expiry associated with it.

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes uses `TokenRequest` API to generate tokens automatically bound to SA: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/authentication-resources/token-request-v1/

The official Kubernetes documentation also says:

> You can still manually create a service account token Secret; for example, if you need a token that never expires.

It means the only way to create a non-expired token is to **manually create a service account's token Secret**. By default, created secrets (any kind) don't have expiration details.

With `TokenRequest,` it was also achievable via the `kubectl create token my_token --duration=0s` flag, but it has been removed since 1.24.

Comment: Thanks .. How to mount this manually created token into the pod

Comment: Just mount secret normally: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/website/main/content/en/examples/secret/dotfile-secret.yaml

Comment: Thanks a lot. It clarified my doubts.